# How to solve the Elasticsearch failing when searching by LocalDate.MAX?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch to search for something between `2010-01-01` and `LocalDate.MAX` which fails with:

```
nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=arithmetic_exception, reason=long overflow]]
```

Having `springDataElasticsearchRepository.findByAgeBetween(startLocalDate, endLocalDate)`.

What is the maximum date Elasticsearch accepts or how should otherwise avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch stores dates as long values representing milliseconds since epoch. If you run the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long maxLong = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(maxLong);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(zonedDateTime);
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
```

you will get

```
+292278994-08-17
```

as the maximum date that is representable. The maximum `LocalDate` value is

```
+999999999-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `springDataElasticsearchRepository.findByAgeBetween(Optional<LocalDate> startLocalDate, Optional<LocalDate> endLocalDate)` allows for avoiding `LocalDate.MIN` and `LocalDate.MAX` which are causing troubles.